# Merging two data frames in R by matching key

Tags: r, merge, matching

I have two data frames DFS and DFE. DFS has the start dates at which a set of employees started a job. and DFE has the end dates at which they completed the job. The order in which the employee IDs appear in the two frames may be different.

```
DFS <- data.frame(ID=c('ID1','ID2','ID3'), begin=c('3/1/06 18:20', '2/1/07 15:30', '5/3/06 9:00'));
DFE <- data.frame(ID=c('ID3', 'ID2','ID1'), end=c('4/1/10 12:00', '6/1/11 14:20', '1/1/09 11:10'));
```

I want to create a data frame that matches the begin end end dates for each employee (e.g. output below):

```
DFR <-data.frame(ID=c('ID1','ID2','ID3'), begin=c('3/1/06 18:20', '2/1/07 15:30', '5/3/06 9:00'),
               end=c('1/1/09 11:10', '6/1/11 14:20','4/1/10 12:00' )  );
```

This can be done in a loop. But I would like to know if  there is an alternative method for matching and merging in R that does not involve loops. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

`merge` does what you want.  It will create a data frame of the joined data.  Here, you want to join on the `ID` column, which is specified with `by`.

`by` defaults to the intersection of the column names between the data frames, so if there are no other common columns, it need not be specified.

```
merge(DFS, DFE, by='ID')
##    ID        begin          end
## 1 ID1 3/1/06 18:20 1/1/09 11:10
## 2 ID2 2/1/07 15:30 6/1/11 14:20
## 3 ID3  5/3/06 9:00 4/1/10 12:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, the two data frames have other columns about the employee that may be common to both. For example, both DFS and DFE contain the employee's address and age. Will merge() work in that case as well? Thanks.

Comment: It will.  If there are other columns with the same names that you don't want to use for matching, you need to supply the `by` argument.

Comment: every time I try to use ``merge`` I end up with ``value.x`` and ``value.y`` instead of the expected ``value`` and end up looking for another solution...